# Passing a function into another function that integrates the 1st function

Tags: functions, function-construction

for example I have

```
a = Sin[t]
```

and then I have

```
f[a_] := Integrate[a, {x, 0, pi}]
```

Will it work?

Will the `t` in the sine expression be changed to 0 and `Pi`?

I don't define the 't' as an input to the function. If I run it, it'll probably just integrate the sine, but it didn't put the 0 and the pi to the sin.

I want the 0 and the `Pi` to be in the sine, but I don't know how to do it because I am still learning the Wolfram Language.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your "will it work" question. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your questions is ***no***.

But this will work:

```
a = Sin;
f[func_] := Integrate[func[x], {x, 0, Pi}]
f[a]
f[Cos]
```

> `2`
> `0`

#### Update

The following is added to address concerns raised by the OP in a comment to this answer.

Your function `f` has been written to expect an argument that can be used as the head of a function call. `Sin[x] - Cos[x]` is an expression that cannot be used in that manner: `Integrate` would see `(Sin[x] - Cos[x])[x]` which is not a valid integrand.

So if you are going to give `f` an expression, it needs to be converted into a function before it is passed. Here are two ways to do it.

Define a new function that evaluates to the expression.

```
g[x_] := Sin[x] - Cos[x]
f[g]
```

> `2`

Convert the expression into a pure function  (look up [`Function`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) in the documentation).

```
f[Sin[#] - Cos[#] &]
```

> `2`

Comment: what if I want to have 2 different function ? for example, integrate [ sin[x] - cos [x] ]

Comment: @Gokturkgokturk.I have addressed your concern in an update to my answer.